# Creating a trigger on Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to send telemetry messages into a database whose architecture is below.

I currently have 5 tables, whose columns are the following:

- Table Device (DeviceID (PK), Firmware)
- Table RawMessage (DeviceID (PK), Timestamp (PK), RawData)
- Table Temperature (DeviceID (PK), Timestamp (PK), Temperature)
- Table Humidity (DeviceID (PK), Timestamp (PK), Humidity)
- Table Config (Device ID (PK), Timestamp (PK), Config)

For each message sent by a device, the RawData field includes the message type (temperature, humidity or config) and the rest of the payload.

Also, depending on the firmware version, the encryption is not identical from one device to another.

The mechanism I have tried to implement is to send the message in the RawMessage table, then a trigger would check the firmware version in the Device table to decode the RawData correctly and send the message either in the Measure or Config table.

My code is below:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER message_conversion BEFORE INSERT ON RawMessage
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF (SELECT Firmware FROM Device WHERE (DeviceID = NEW.DeviceID))='v3'
        OR (SELECT Firmware FROM Device WHERE (DeviceID = NEW.DeviceID))='v4'
            THEN
                /* Checking message type */
                IF (LEFT(NEW.RawData, 1) = '1') OR (LEFT(NEW.RawData, 1) = '2')
                    THEN INSERT INTO Temperature (DeviceID, Timestamp, Temperature)
                        VALUES (NEW.DeviceID, NEW.Timestamp, SUBSTRING(NEW.RawData, 2,3));
                ELSEIF (LEFT(NEW.RawData, 1) = '3') OR (LEFT(NEW.RawData, 1) = '4')
                    THEN INSERT INTO Humidity (DeviceID, Timestamp, Humidity)
                        VALUES (NEW.DeviceID, NEW.Timestamp, SUBSTRING(NEW.RawData, 2, 4));
                ELSE INSERT INTO Config (DeviceID, Timestamp, Config)
                    VALUES (NEW.DeviceID, NEW.Timestamp, SUBSTRING(NEW.RawData, 2, 6));
                ENDIF;
        /* Here I would have put a ELSE IF to manage the other firmwares, but I saw in other posts it would raise en error */
        ELSEIF (LEFT(NEW.RawData, 1) = '1') OR (LEFT(NEW.RawData, 1) = '3')
                                    THEN INSERT INTO Temperature (DeviceID, Timestamp, Temperature)
                        VALUES (NEW.DeviceID, NEW.Timestamp, SUBSTRING(NEW.RawData, 2,4));
                ELSEIF (LEFT(NEW.RawData, 1) = '2') OR (LEFT(NEW.RawData, 1) = '5')
                    THEN INSERT INTO Humidity (DeviceID, Timestamp, Humidity)
                        VALUES (NEW.DeviceID, NEW.Timestamp, SUBSTRING(NEW.RawData, 2, 3));
                ELSE INSERT INTO Config (DeviceID, Timestamp, Config)
                    VALUES (NEW.DeviceID, NEW.Timestamp, SUBSTRING(NEW.RawData, 2, 6));
        ENDIF;
    END$$
```

I get many errors with this code :

- Incorrect syntax near $ (looks like DELIMITER word is not taken into consideration)
- 'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch.
- Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.
- Incorrect syntax near 'elseif'.

EDIT : the previous code uses MySQL syntax. Below is an attempt with SQL syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER message_conversion BEFORE INSERT ON RawMesage
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DeviceID varchar(8);
    DECLARE @Timestamp datetime;
    DECLARE @MessageType varchar(1);
    DECLARE @Temperature float;
    DECLARE @Humidity float;
    DECLARE @Config varchar(6);

    SELECT @DeviceID = newMsg.DeviceID FROM inserted newMsg;
    SELECT @Timestamp = newMsg.Timestamp FROM inserted newMsg;
    SELECT @MessageType = LEFT(newMsg.RawData, 1) FROM inserted newMsg;
    SELECT @TemperatureV3 = SUBSTRING(newMsg.RawData, 2, 3) FROM inserted newMsg;
    SELECT @TemperatureV1 = SUBSTRING(newMsg.RawData, 2, 4) FROM inserted newMsg;
    SELECT @HumidityV3 = SUBSTRING(newMsg.RawData, 2, 4) FROM inserted newMsg;
    SELECT @HumidityV1 = SUBSTRING(newMsg.RawData, 2, 3) FROM inserted newMsg;
    SELECT @Config = SUBSTRING(newMsg.RawData, 2, 6) FROM inserted newMsg;

    CASE
        WHEN (FirmwareVersion FROM Device WHERE DeviceID = @DeviceID) = 'v3' 
        OR (FirmwareVersion FROM Device WHERE DeviceID = @DeviceID) = 'v4'
            THEN CASE
                     WHEN (@MessageType = '1' OR @MessageType = '2')
                         THEN INSERT INTO Temperature (DeviceID, Timestamp, Temperature)
                         VALUES (@DeviceID, @Timestamp, @TemperatureV3);
                     WHEN (@MessageType = '3' OR @MessageType = '4')
                         THEN INSERT INTO Humidity(DeviceID, Timestamp, Humidity)
                         VALUES (@DeviceID, @Timestamp, @HumidityV3);
                     ELSE INSERT INTO Config (DeviceID, Timestamp, Config)
                         VALUES (@DeviceID, @Timestamp, @Config);

        ELSE CASE WHEN (@MessageType = '1' OR @MessageType = '3')
                      THEN INSERT INTO Temperature (DeviceID, Timestamp, Temperature)
                      VALUES (@DeviceID, @Timestamp, @TemperatureV1);
                  WHEN (@MessageType = '2' OR @MessageType = '4')
                      THEN INSERT INTO Humidity(DeviceID, Timestamp, Humidity)
                      VALUES (@DeviceID, @Timestamp, @HumidityV1);
                  ELSE INSERT INTO Config (DeviceID, Timestamp, Config)
                      VALUES (@DeviceID, @Timestamp, @Config);
```

Comment: what does the Payload or RawData look like when do the inserted into the RawMessage table?

Comment: What's the type of your Azure SQL? SQLServer or MySQL? DELIMITER  seems to be a key word of MySQL.

Comment: The raw payload is an hexadecimal string, that can be split then converted for each measure.
Indeed this looks like MySQL keywords even tough I have deployed SQL Server
I have modified the code accordingly.

Comment: Not to be offensive or obtuse, but everything about the architecture you describe, the errors, and the mere use of SQL triggers smells very badly.  If you have the opportunity to stop and rethink everything, id strongly advise it. That being said I truly wish you success and prove my intuition is incorrect.

Comment: agree. Triggers are trouble. As an ingestion mechanism they're more trouble. I suggest a recurring process that batches incoming messages for processing instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have removed all the conversion within a decoding function, and the trigger only calls the function and fills out the other tables.
I had already tried another architecture with the decoding taking place before populating SQL database. The Azure component (Stream Analytics) would prepare the data for each table then populate them. The only issue with this method is that I was unable to get the firmware version, as I couldn't send a request to the database, wait for the answer, then populate the appropriate tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSSQL does not support BEFORE triggers. The closest you have is INSTEAD OF triggers but their behavior is different to that of BEFORE triggers in MySQL.

We can use the IF statement in Azure SQL.
The following illustrates the syntax of the IF statement:

```sql
IF boolean_expression   
BEGIN
    { statement_block }
END
```

I tried to correct the code as follows:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trg_message_conversion  ON  [dbo].[RawMessage]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DeviceID varchar(8);
    DECLARE @Timestamp datetime;
    DECLARE @MessageType varchar(1);
    DECLARE @Temperature float;
    DECLARE @Humidity float;
    DECLARE @Config varchar(6);
    DECLARE @TemperatureV3 varchar(3);
    DECLARE @TemperatureV1 varchar(4);
    DECLARE @HumidityV3 varchar(4);
    DECLARE @HumidityV1 varchar(3);

    SELECT @DeviceID = newMsg.DeviceID FROM inserted newMsg;
    SELECT @Timestamp = newMsg.Timestamp FROM inserted newMsg;
    SELECT @MessageType = LEFT(newMsg.RawData, 1) FROM inserted newMsg;
    SELECT @TemperatureV3 = SUBSTRING(newMsg.RawData, 2, 3) FROM inserted newMsg;
    SELECT @TemperatureV1 = SUBSTRING(newMsg.RawData, 2, 4) FROM inserted newMsg;
    SELECT @HumidityV3 = SUBSTRING(newMsg.RawData, 2, 4) FROM inserted newMsg;
    SELECT @HumidityV1 = SUBSTRING(newMsg.RawData, 2, 3) FROM inserted newMsg;
    SELECT @Config = SUBSTRING(newMsg.RawData, 2, 6) FROM inserted newMsg;

IF (select Firmware FROM Device WHERE DeviceID = @DeviceID) = 'v3' 
        OR (select Firmware FROM Device WHERE DeviceID = @DeviceID) = 'v4'
    BEGIN        
        IF @MessageType = '1' OR @MessageType = '2'
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Temperature (DeviceID, Timestamp, Temperature)
                VALUES (@DeviceID, @Timestamp, @TemperatureV3);
            END
            
        IF @MessageType = '3' OR @MessageType = '4'
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Humidity(DeviceID, Timestamp, Humidity)
                    VALUES (@DeviceID, @Timestamp, @HumidityV3);
            END
        ELSE 
                INSERT INTO Config (DeviceID, Timestamp, Config)
                VALUES (@DeviceID, @Timestamp, @Config);
    END

ELSE

    BEGIN
        IF @MessageType = '1' OR @MessageType = '3'
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Temperature (DeviceID, Timestamp, Temperature)
                VALUES (@DeviceID, @Timestamp, @TemperatureV1);
            END

        IF @MessageType = '2' OR @MessageType = '4'
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO Humidity(DeviceID, Timestamp, Humidity)
                VALUES (@DeviceID, @Timestamp, @HumidityV1);
            END
                
        ELSE INSERT INTO Config (DeviceID, Timestamp, Config)
                VALUES (@DeviceID, @Timestamp, @Config);
    END
END
```

You can try it.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed it seems to work with IF...BEGIN...END statements :)